# The best approach to make a report based in dynamic data

Tags: database-design

I have an Asp.Net MVC application where I need to create a report.
This report will show some data about an entity (activities), but only activities of ONE specific type that will be inserted in the database (until now).

My data model is:

Activity:

```
Int ID
DateTime Date
Int TypeId
```

Activity Type:

```
Int ID
String TypeName
```

As activity type doesn't exist yet, how would one implement this report?

I thought about adding one property to Activity Type:

```
Bool IsXYZ //(hypothetic name here)
```

And then render my report showing only activities where the type have "IsXYZ==true".

But I really don't know if this is the best approach to do this.

I tried to search about how to do this, but I don't know how this is called (or even if this has a name).

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. Are these properties on objects, or fields in a database? If the latter, are you trying to generate the report out of an SQL query or is there a programming language involved? If there is a programming language involved the obvious answer is "use polymorphism" since pretty much every language supports that, so where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I ended up with the following solution:

I added a new "key" property in my "Activity Type" entity.

And in the report, I will filter data from my db by looking for a specific "key" value.

Later, the user can configure which Activity type they want to see in the report just by editing this key value.
For example:

- The report will look in the database for activities whose type has
  a specific key, let's say "XYZ".
- The user then just needs to edit the activity types that they want to be
  shown in the report by adding this key value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is the PK of each table, and that there is a FK in ACTIVITY_TYPE pointing to ACTIVITY (typeid --> id)

- User selects an activity type from a dropdown list (by name)
- Dropwodn list returns ID of selected activity type
- This query is run (substituting 999 with the ID of the activity type user selected):

  ---

  ```sql
      select a.id,a.date,t.typename
      from
          activity a join activity_type t 
          on (a.typeid=t.id)
      where
          a.typeid = 999;
  ```

  ---
- If no rows are returned, inform that to the user or draw/print an empty report.
- If rows are returned, show/print the report.